# How to draw a 3D cylinder model cross section

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am trying to use \tikzpicture to draw a cross section isometric view of a model I am working with.

I have attached a photo below showing the desired view with dimensions.

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

(Apologies for the drawing)

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a do-it-for-me question that does not show effort or prior research from the OP.

Comment: As someone that is new to LaTeX and pressed for time to complete this piece of work - I had a look through any related questions on this site but couldn’t quite get it to work the way I wanted. 

If it makes you feel better voting me down, then you do what makes you happy - no hard feelings :)

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: If you are working on a tight deadline, tikz probably is not the better choice, if you don't master it ;)

Comment: @gs00350 if you already made an attempt to make it work then you can add that attempt to your question, with some specific issues that presented you with a problem (for example: "this is my code for drawing _40cm_ with an arrow but I don't know how to rotate it"). When you show your effort then many people here will be willing to help you to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is to give you a start. It is not an attempt to fully redraw the picture. It does, however, provide you with most of it, the rest is IMHO repetition.

In more detail,

- in order to install the 3d view, the `perspective` library is employed. (IMHO the statement `isometric view` only makes sense if one additionally specifies the orientation of the cylinder in 3d space.)
- lengths are stored in "functions" via `declare function`.
- this is Ti*k*Z, so we need to draw the various faces in the appropriate order. If you do not like this, switch to `asymptote`.

Code and result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,semithick,line cap=round,
    declare function={R=20;d=9;dd=1.5;rr=5;L=10;l=1;},%<- d/2efine some lengths
    scale=0.15]
 \begin{scope}[3d view={30}{10}]%<- install 3d view and set view angles
  \path[fill=gray!80] plot[variable=\t,domain=60:110,smooth] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{d/2},{R*sin(\t)})
   --   plot[variable=\t,domain=110:60,smooth] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{R*sin(\t)}) -- cycle;
  \path[fill=gray!40] plot[variable=\t,domain=120:240,smooth] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{R*sin(\t)}) 
      --   plot[variable=\t,domain=240:120,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{rr*sin(\t)}) --cycle;
  \path[fill=black]  plot[variable=\t,domain=120:240,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{rr*sin(\t)})
     -- ({rr*cos(240)},{d/2},{rr*sin(240)}) 
     -- ({(rr+dd)*cos(240)},{d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(240)})
   -- plot[variable=\t,domain=240:120,smooth] 
     ({(rr+dd)*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(\t)}) -- cycle;     
  \path[fill=brown!40] plot[variable=\t,domain=120:60,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{d/2+l},{rr*sin(\t)}) --
     plot[variable=\t,domain=60:120,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2-L},{rr*sin(\t)}) --
     cycle;  
  \path[fill=gray!40] plot[variable=\t,domain=60:120,smooth] 
     ({R*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{R*sin(\t)}) 
      --   plot[variable=\t,domain=120:60,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{rr*sin(\t)}) --cycle;
  \path[fill=black]  plot[variable=\t,domain=120:60,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{rr*sin(\t)})
     -- ({rr*cos(60)},{d/2},{rr*sin(60)})   
     -- ({(rr+dd)*cos(60)},{d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(60)})
   -- plot[variable=\t,domain=60:120,smooth] 
     ({(rr+dd)*cos(\t)},{-d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(\t)}) -- cycle;     
  \path[fill=gray!60]    
    ({(rr+dd)*cos(60)},{-d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(60)}) 
    -- ({(rr+dd)*cos(60)},{d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(60)})
    -- ({R*cos(60)},{d/2},{R*sin(60)})
    -- ({R*cos(60)},{-d/2},{R*sin(60)}) -- cycle;
  \path[fill=brown!60] plot[variable=\t,domain=240:60,smooth] 
     ({rr*cos(\t)},{-d/2-L},{rr*sin(\t)}) --cycle;   
  \path[fill=brown] 
     ({rr*cos(240)},{-d/2-L},{rr*sin(240)}) 
     -- ({rr*cos(60)},{-d/2-L},{rr*sin(60)}) 
     -- ({rr*cos(60)},{d/2+l},{rr*sin(60)}) 
     -- ({rr*cos(240)},{d/2+l},{rr*sin(240)}) 
     --cycle;    
  \path[fill=gray!60]    
    ({(rr+dd)*cos(240)},{-d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(240)}) 
    -- ({(rr+dd)*cos(240)},{d/2},{(rr+dd)*sin(240)})
    -- ({R*cos(240)},{d/2},{R*sin(240)})
    -- ({R*cos(240)},{-d/2},{R*sin(240)}) -- cycle;
 \end{scope}  
 %
 \begin{scope}[xshift=35cm]
  \draw (-d/2,-R) rectangle (d/2,-rr-dd) (-d/2,R) rectangle (d/2,rr+dd)
   (-d/2-L,-rr) rectangle (d/2+l,rr);
  \draw[fill] (-d/2,-rr) rectangle (d/2,-rr-dd)
  (-d/2,rr) rectangle (d/2,rr+dd);
  \draw[dashed] (d/2,R) -- ++ (5,0) coordinate (rt)
     (d/2,-R) -- ++ (5,0) coordinate (rb);
  \draw[<->] (rt) -- (rb) node[midway,rotate=90,anchor=north]
     {\pgfmathparse{2*R}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult\,mm};
  \draw[<->] (-d/2,R+1) --  (d/2,R+1) node[midway,rotate=90,anchor=west]
  {\pgfmathparse{d}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult\,mm};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]